# Append output to an existing Excel File using OpenPyXL

Tags: python, excel, append, openpyxl

Step 1. Take input from an excel file.

Step 2. Ceate WB object.

Step 3. Take data from that WB object and create a list of dictionaries.

Step 4. Manipulate, Format, style the data.

Step 5. Now need to output the data and APPEND it into an Existing Excel Workbook.
Meaning the Existing Excel Workbook will be appended with the new data from
Step 1 constantly.

I have Steps 1 - 4 down and can output my data to a NEW workbook.  I am coming up 
empty on Step 5.

Any guidance or direction would be appreciated.

```
###  Python 3.X  ###
import sys
import time
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import Alignment, Font, Style
from openpyxl.cell import get_column_letter
from pathlib import Path

###Double Click a Batch file, CMD opens, Client drags and drops excel File            
###to be Formatted

try:
    path = sys.argv[1]
except IndexError:
    path = Path(input('Input file to read: ').strip("'").strip('"'))

output_string = str(Path(path.parent, path.stem + '.NewFormatted.xlsx'))

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(str(path))
sheet1 = wb.worksheet[0]

###Do the Python Dance on Data###

###Style, Font, Alignment applied to sheets###

###Currently Saves output as a NEW excel File in the Directory the original    
###file was drag and dropped from

wb.save(output_string)

###Need the output to be appended to an existing Excel file already present      
###in a target directory

###Note Formatted Workbook (output) has multiple sheets###
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

openpyxl will let you edit existing workbooks including appending data to them. But the methods provided are limited to individual items of data such as the cells. There are no aggregate functions for copying things like worksheets from one workbook to another.

Comment: Your reply is greatly appreciated.  This is  unfortunate as now I need to find another way to take Excel data in and output to an existing Excel file.